# Hooking up a websocket to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, sockets, websocket

I'm having an issue with connecting my websocket on port 7777 to my aws deployment. I am new to sockets and deployment. I have my main port 8081 hooked up, but having issues with the websocket. I've been at this for a day and would like some pointers! Thanks!

Currently, receiving this error:

[image]

React code

```
import React from 'react';
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';
let socket = openSocket('http://my-api.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com:7777', { transports: ['websocket'] });
export class HomePage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    channels: null,
    channelSelected: false,
    socket: null,
    typers: {},
    channel: 1,
    messages: [],
    msg: ''
  }
  socket;
  componentDidMount() {
   
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.username && !this.state.channelSelected) {
      this.configureSocket();
      this.setState({ channel: 1, channelSelected: true });
      this.socket.emit('joinChannel', { channel: 1, username: this.props.username });
    }
  }
  configureSocket = () => {
    socket.on('connection', () => {
      if (this.state.channel) {
        this.handleChannelSelect(this.state.channel.id);
      }
    });
    socket.on('incomingChat', username => {
      let typers = this.state.typers;
      if (!typers[username]) {
        typers[username] = 1;
        this.setState({ typers })
      }
    });

    socket.on('clearingChat', username => {
      let typers = this.state.typers;
      delete typers[username]
      this.setState({ typers });
    });

    socket.on('incomingMessage', details => {
      let messages = this.state.messages;
      let typers = this.state.typers;
      delete typers[details.username]
      messages.push(details);
      this.setState({ messages, typers });
    })
    socket.on('channel', channel => {
      let channels = this.state.channels;
      channels.forEach(c => {
        if (c.id === channel.id) {
          c.participants = channel.participants;
        }
      });
      this.setState({ channels });
    });
    socket.on('message', message => {

      let channels = this.state.channels
      channels.forEach(c => {
        if (c.id === message.channel_id) {
          if (!c.messages) {
            c.messages = [message];
          } else {
            c.messages.push(message);
          }
        }
      });
      this.setState({ channels });
    });
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  
  handleChannelSelect = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ channel: 1 });
    this.socket.emit('leaveChannel', this.props.username);
  }

  handleSendMessage = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.socket.emit('send-message', { msg: this.state.msg, username: this.props.username, channel: this.state.channel });
    this.setState({ msg: '' });
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ msg: value });
    if (!value) this.socket.emit('addingMessage', { username: this.props.username, msg: 'cleared' });
    if(value) this.socket.emit('addingMessage', { username: this.props.username, msg: value });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className='chat-app'>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSendMessage}>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.msg} />
        </form>
        <button onClick={this.handleChannelSelect}></button>
        { this.state.messages.length > 0 && this.state.messages.map(({ username, msg }) => <p key={Math.random()}>{`${username}: ${msg}`}</p>) }

        {Object.keys(this.state.typers).length > 0 && Object.keys(this.state.typers).map(el => el !== this.props.username  && <p>{`${el} typing....`}</p>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

server code

```
const app = require("./app");
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const db = require("./db");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const em = express();
const server = http.createServer(em);
const chatPort = process.env.LIVE_CHAT_PORT || 7777;
const io = socketio(server);
server.listen(chatPort, () => {
  console.log(`Live Chat sock running on port ${chatPort}`)
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081, () => {
  console.log("Listening on PORT 8081");
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
  let user;
  socket.on('joinChannel', async ({ username, channel }) => {
    user = userJoin(socket.id, username, channel);
    socket.on('addingMessage', details => {
      const { username, msg } = details;
      if (msg === 'cleared') {
        io.to(user.room).emit('clearingChat', username);
      } else {
        io.to(user.room).emit('incomingChat', username);
      }
    })
    socket.join(user.room);
  });
  socket.on('send-message', async details => {
    const { msg, username, channel } = details;
    let em = await db.query(`
      INSERT INTO messages(conversation_id, user_id, shared_post, message, posted)
      VALUES($1, $2, null, $3, current_timestamp)
      RETURNING id;
    `, [channel, username, msg])
    io.to(user.room).emit('incomingMessage', details)
  })
  
  socket.on('leaveChannel', username => {
    const user = userLeave(username);
    socket.disconnect();

  });
  });
```